# Lightning map Marker CSS

Tags: lightning, javascript, css, error

Good Morning.
A few days ago, the Lightning Map Marker CSS stopped working. As shown in the image below, the return is in "String" format instead of "Tag".

Was there an update to the Lightning map that may have caused this?

[image]

Comment: is it Aura or LWC

Comment: Aura @User6670 
As I said, it worked. Before, it displayed an image, a link ... But it started to come in a string format.

Comment: Same with LWC, it used to work and stopped. I suspect in Summer 20 they fixed the issue as technically the fact it was working was injection :( this is pretty annoying as formatting is incredibly limited but we had the same experience.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/documentation

- title: "HTML tags aren't supported and are displayed as unescaped markup."
- description: "A subset of HTML tags is supported."

As well as: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_components.htm&release=226&type=5

**lightning-map**

> The following attribute has changed. map-markers—HTML tags you include
> in the title property are displayed as unescaped markup in the
> location list and info window. A subset of HTML tags are supported for
> use with the description property. The tags are: b, br, del, em,
> h1-h6, i, ins, mark, p, small, strong, sub, and sup.

So yes, that changed. I think I read somewhere that it was basically an undocumented feature but of course they had to sanitize/disallow it due to security concerns.

Comment: This is a super late answer - but I just stumbled upon this question. Maybe it still helps someone.